# How to make current webpage in WKWebView to receive mouse movements when it isn't focused (key window, on macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, wkwebview, appkit

I know it's a rare circumstance, however, I have no choice.

I created a NSWindow to be displayed over the desktop as a dynamic wallpaper, setting its styleMask as `.borderless` to hide its title bar and its level to `NSWindow.Level(Int(CGWindowLevelForKey(.desktopWindow)))`, with a WKWebView in its contentView.

That means it can't become key or main window. What's more, the window's interactive space is obstructed by the Finder app on the desktop.

My approach is using `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents` for observing global keyboard & mouse events and forward it by calling `webview.mouseMoved(event)`.

```
func setEventHandler() {
        self.eventHandler = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .any) { [weak self] event in
            // contentView.subviews.first -> SwiftUIView.subviews.first -> WKWebView
            if let webview = self?.wallpaperWindow.contentView?.subviews.first?.subviews.first,
               let frontmostApplication = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication,
                   webview is WKWebView,
                   frontmostApplication.bundleIdentifier == "com.apple.finder" {
                switch event.type {
                case .scrollWheel:
                    var modified = event
                    webview.scrollWheel(with: event)
                case .mouseMoved:
                    webview.mouseMoved(with: event)
                case .mouseEntered:
                    webview.mouseEntered(with: event)
                case .mouseExited:
                    webview.mouseExited(with: event)

                case .leftMouseUp:
                    fallthrough
                case .rightMouseUp:
                    webview.mouseUp(with: event)
                    
                case .leftMouseDown:
                    webview.mouseDown(with: event)
    //            case .rightMouseDown:
    //                view?.mouseDown(with: event)
                    
                case .leftMouseDragged:
                    fallthrough
                case .rightMouseDragged:
                    webview.mouseDragged(with: event)
                    
                default:
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But it isn't perfect, mouse movements are still ignored.

So I wondered if there's a way to make the WKWebView to process the mouse events it receives to the web page without being key window, like a hover effect and so on.

Comment: What debugging have you done? Is your monitor firing? Is the line `webview.mouseMoved(with: event)`? getting hit?

Comment: The debugging result is that the monitor is firing indeed, every type of event it monitored is getting hit except `webview.mouseMoved(with: event)`

Comment: I tried your code and `webview.mouseMoved(with: event)` is hit but `WKWebView.mouseMoved(with:)` is not implemented.